# Extra property on test task not keeping value

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying to add some set up and tear down code to a gradle build that is using the Java plugin test task for running the JUnit tests.  I have an extral resource that has to be set up prior to the tests and then torn down when the test is over.

When I use the `test.doLast` feature, the resource is properly torn down unless there is a test failure, in which case the `doLast` is skipped.

I've tried to create a finalizer task, but it runs every time whether the resource was set up in the `doFirst` or whether it was skipped because all the targets are up to date.  I need to skip the finalizer task when the `doFirst` was not run.

What I've been trying to do is add an extra property to the test task that I set during the do first and then bail out of the finalizer if it hasn't been set.  My problem is that when I get to the finalizer task, the test property is no longer set.

What is the correct approach for passing a variable like this from the doFirst task to the finalizer?  Below is a minimal version of the code I'm using.

```
test.ext {
  resourceStarted = false
}

task tearDownResource {
  if (!test.resourceStarted) return
  // tear down resource here
}

test.finalizedBy tearDownResource

test.doFirst {
  resourceStarted = true
  // start up resource
}
```

When the finalizer runs the `test.resourceStarted` property is always false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Common mistake: your code in tearDownResource is run during configuration. Try

`task tearDownResource << {`

or put it into `doFirst`/`doLast`

Comment: I thought it might be something like that, but the docs weren't entirely clear about the difference between a task an a closure.